# Making animated movie and embed in game in unity3d

Tags: video, unity-game-engine, 3d, game-engine, animated

I want to make a 3D animated movie/video so that I can embed it after my game level made in Unity3D.

May anyone tell me the free software that I can use for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, Blender is the best open source software to make 3d movie. Also, Unity supports blender file to import.

Comment: But importing blender file will make the game heavier...don't you think so??

Comment: Well, in my opinion, other open sources 3d animation software is not capable as much as Blender. Also, how many open sources software are supported in Unity, very few as far I know. Also, same game character model can be user for both gameplay and game movie. And, now a days, blender export supports many format with many settings which generates small files. Last thing is, many developers are using blender in Unity. So, for any case, you will better get community support. This is all my opinion. Suitability varies from person to person, project to project and aspect to aspect. Good Luck !!!